# Sorting based on column in join model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, has-many-through, join

I followed [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists-revised?view=comments) to make a sortable list of items, which works great for one model, but I need to sort items that are organized by a join model, and can't figure out how to do it. Here is an example:

I want to organize all the cycles that are in a program by the `cycle_order` column.

The `cycle_order` column is in the `cycles_programs` table

For good measure, see picture of the join table at the bottom.

```
class Cycle 

  has_many :cycles_programs
  has_many :programs, :through => :cycles_programs

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :programs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cycles_programs, allow_destroy: :true

class CyclesProgram

  belongs_to :program
  belongs_to :cycle

class Program 

  has_many :cycles_programs
  has_many :cycles, :through => :cycles_programs

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cycles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cycles_programs, allow_destroy: :true
```

Here is the Schema:

```
create_table "programs", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at",    :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    :null => false
  end

create_table "cycles_programs", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "program_id"
    t.integer  "cycle_id"
    t.integer  "cycle_order"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  end

create_table "cycles", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a default scope to `CyclesGroup`

```
default_scope -> { order(:group_order) }
```

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is so simple. Just add `default_scope -> { order(:cycle)order) }` to the `CyclesProgram` model